# how put limit to items in rethinkdb

Tags: javascript, rethinkdb, nosql

i have table in rethinkdb that have much fields and items, i want get all data that this table but in the case of items i only want the 2 last records: look the results and the query

```
r.db('db').table('table1').filter(function(opentb1){
  return openTb1('chat').match('(user_273_1|user_1_273)')
})
```

and show it:

```
{
  "adm":  "1" ,
  "chat":  "user_273_1" ,
  "id":  "09ce2adc-9d49-4830-9fb6-fb7159f92d08" ,
  "msg": [
      {
          "date":  "2016-07-20T01:43:06.302Z" ,
          "id":  "4e1d85e0-4e1b-11e6-bb9f-2bb985f41f5d" ,
          "msg":  "sgzsrgz" ,
          "nick":  "SonickSeven" ,
          "user":  "1"
      } ,
      {
          "date":  "2016-07-20T01:43:08.832Z" ,
          "id":  "4f9f9200-4e1b-11e6-bb9f-2bb985f41f5d" ,
          "msg":  "egser" ,
          "nick":  "SonickSeven" ,
          "user":  "1"
      } ,
      {
          "date":  "2016-07-20T01:43:55.233Z" ,
          "id":  "6b47cd10-4e1b-11e6-bb9f-2bb985f41f5d" ,
          "msg":  "sergse" ,
          "nick":  "SonickSeven" ,
          "user":  "1"
      }
  ],
  "optChat": [
      {
      "height": 0 ,
      "minizar": true ,
      "position": false ,
      "user":  "1" ,
      "user2":  "273" ,
      "width": 0 ,
      "x": 0 ,
      "y": 0
      }
  ]
}
```

but i want that only show the last 2 items in subfield:"msg" show some like it:

```
{
  "adm":  "1" ,
  "chat":  "user_273_1" ,
  "id":  "09ce2adc-9d49-4830-9fb6-fb7159f92d08" ,
  "msg": [
      {
          "date":  "2016-07-20T01:43:08.832Z" ,
          "id":  "4f9f9200-4e1b-11e6-bb9f-2bb985f41f5d" ,
          "msg":  "egser" ,
          "nick":  "SonickSeven" ,
          "user":  "1"
      } ,
      {
          "date":  "2016-07-20T01:43:55.233Z" ,
          "id":  "6b47cd10-4e1b-11e6-bb9f-2bb985f41f5d" ,
          "msg":  "sergse" ,
          "nick":  "SonickSeven" ,
          "user":  "1"
      }
  ],
  "optChat": [
      {
      "height": 0 ,
      "minizar": true ,
      "position": false ,
      "user":  "1" ,
      "user2":  "273" ,
      "width": 0 ,
      "x": 0 ,
      "y": 0
      }
  ]
}
```

how i can it possible, i had searched this solve it in internet but i don't match nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add `.merge(function(row) { return {msg: row('msg').slice(-2)}; })` to the end of your query.